# Can my CSR contain the expiration date of my certificate?

Tags: openssl

I generated a CSR file I would like to send to my upstream CA. When decoding my CSR file I don't see any `expiry` / `validity` extension(s) or anything similar.

I know my upstream CA has a `max-validity` parameter that basically defines the max validity of a certificate it signs but I would like to know if I can change this parameter via the CSR?

I tried `-days` when generating my CSR but it doesn't seem to have any impact. When the upstream CA signs my cert, the `noAfter` value is still the one configured in the upstream CA.

Let's say the `max-validity` on the upstream CA is a year, can I somehow overwrite this value with a smaller one so my local certificate is only valid say a month instead of a year?

Thanks!